# Does BigQuery has alter session like oracle(exp:ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT)

Tags: oracle, google-bigquery, alter

How to convert oracle alter session to BigQuery?

example:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYY/MM/DD';
ALTER SESSION FORCE PARALLEL QUERY PARALLEL 4;
```

Comment: It would probably be helpful to provide context about what session is in Oracle.  In general though, BQ is mostly auto-managed for you, so you shouldn't have to do much configuration for users and connections.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.